# show that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac {2n(-1)^{n}}{4^{n+1}} = -2/25$

Tags: sequences-and-series

I'm having trouble to show that:
$$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac {2n(-1)^{n}}{4^{n+1}} = -2/25 $$

What I've tried so far:
simplified the expression to:
$$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n}{2} (\frac{-1}{2})^{n} $$
I've tried to look for anything that looks like a power series to solve the problem, but the n in the numerator troubles me to find that.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: $ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac {2nx^{n}}{4^{n+1}}  \; \;$  converges for $|x| < 4$

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: Yes, but in this question when I'm trying to apply the limit the n in the numerator troubles me to find for what value it converges to. Any tips in how to show that?

Comment: @Shaun Oh! Thanks! I'll edit a little the question!

Comment: @Shaun hope it's better!

Comment: Yes, that's better.

Comment: You need the formula for $n\cdot x^n$ . The trick is to derive the geometric sum with $x^n$ which almost gives the desired expression. Try to work it out.

Comment: @Peter Thanks for the answer! After someone linked the related "already has answers here" I did the question in 3 different ways, and one is by doing the derivation! Thanks for the reply.